# # NameError: global name 'time1' is not defined # maya-python

Tags: python, global, maya

this is my code:

```
def animate(*arg):
    cvList = []
    myList = cm.ls(sl =True)
    randList1 = [rand.uniform(-10,10)for items in range(10)]
    for i in myList:
        cvList = cm.ls(i+".cv[:]" , flatten = True)
    for j in cvList:
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].xValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].xValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].yValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].yValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].zValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].zValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].xValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].xValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].yValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].yValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].zValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].zValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )


animWindow = cm.window(t = 'Animation controls' , w = 150 , menuBar = True , bgc = [.2,.2,.2])
cm.menu(l = 'About' , tearOff = False )
cm.menuItem( l = 'Version 1.0.0')
cm.columnLayout()
cm.text(l = 'Time 1' , w = 150)
time1 = cm.intField()
cm.text(l = 'Time 2' , w = 150)
time = cm.intField()
cm.button(l = 'Set key' , c = animate , w = 150, bgc = [.3,.3,.3])
cm.showWindow(animWindow)
```

this is the error i got:

```
# NameError: global name 'time1' is not defined #
```

i know after that maya wanna tell me time2 is the same

i used this in this one and it's worked:

```
def tinyRandomize(*arg):
    myList = cm.ls (sl = True)
    randoms = [rand.uniform(cm.floatField(Ceil, q = True , v = True),0.5)for i in range(30)]
    for objects in myList:
        cm.xform('%s.cv[0]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[1]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[2]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[3]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[4]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[5]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[6]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[7]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[8]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[9]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[10]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[11]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[12]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[13]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[14]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[15]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[16]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[17]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[18]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[19]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[20]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
```

i added a gui for this def and it's completely worked

please help me.

best regards

Comment: do you need to pass in time1,time2

Comment: Why did you write a function with 21 near-identical copy-pasted lines instead of a 2-line loop?

Comment: Would your first code snippet happen to be inside a class?

Comment: what do you mean actually?

Comment: about 2 line loop ,  i killed myself for doing this but i couldn't do it. how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it's easier, cleaner, and more concise to have a class when creating simple interfaces with default maya UI elements. They get called immediately when defined in **init**() and your interface objects are now in your local scope.

```
import maya.cmds as cm
import random as rand

class RandomAnimation():
    def __init__():
        self.animWindow = cm.window(t = 'Animation controls' , w = 150 , menuBar = True , bgc = [.2,.2,.2])
        cm.menu(l = 'About' , tearOff = False )
        cm.menuItem( l = 'Version 1.0.0')
        self.cLayout = cm.columnLayout()
        self.timeText = cm.text(l = 'Time 1' , w = 150)
        self.time1 = cm.intField()
        self.cm.text(l = 'Time 2' , w = 150)
        self.time = cm.intField()
        self.myButton = cm.button(l = 'Set key' , c = self.animate , w = 150, bgc = [.3,.3,.3])
        cm.showWindow(animWindow)
        # Since the ui is in __init__() it will be ran once the class is instantiated.. 

    def animate(*args):
        # This will gather all of the cvs in all of your selected curves..
        for cv in [for j in [cm.ls(i + ".cv[:]", fl=1) for i in cm.ls(sl=True)]:
            # This will move all the cvs randomly..
            cm.xform(cv, r=1, t=[rand.uniform(-1, 1), rand.uniform(-1, 1), rand.uniform(-1, 1)])
```

Check [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) out for a more thorough explanation on classes.

Answer (score 0):

you declared the variable **time1** outside the def **animate**.  When the function tries to run it doesn't know what time1 is.

@Argiri's answer is the right way to go in the long term - putting UI and callback functions into a class is a cleaner, better way to organize the code.

To make it really clear what's causing the problem, try this:

```
from functools import partial
import random as rand

def animate(time1, time2, ignore):
    print time1, time2, ignore
    cvList = []
    myList = cm.ls(sl =True)
    randList1 = [rand.uniform(-10,10)for items in range(10)]
    for i in myList:
        cvList = cm.ls(i+".cv[:]" , flatten = True)
    for j in cvList:
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].xValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].xValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].yValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].yValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].zValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[0].zValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].xValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].xValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].yValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].yValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].zValue" , t = cm.intField(time1 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )
        cm.setKeyframe(j , ".cv[1].zValue" , t = cm.intField(time2 , query = True , value = True) , v = rand.choice(randList1) )


animWindow = cm.window(t = 'Animation controls' , w = 150 , menuBar = True , bgc = [.2,.2,.2])
cm.menu(l = 'About' , tearOff = False )
cm.menuItem( l = 'Version 1.0.0')
cm.columnLayout()
cm.text(l = 'Time 1' , w = 150)
time1 = cm.intField()
cm.text(l = 'Time 2' , w = 150)
time2 = cm.intField()
cm.button(l = 'Set key' , c = partial(animate, time1, time2) , w = 150, bgc = [.3,.3,.3])
cm.showWindow(animWindow)
```

the module **functools** includes an object called **partial**, which bundles an set of arguments with a function so they can be called together.  By setting the button command to a partial at the time the code runs, you're making sure that when the callback is run the intField objects are going to the function -- so when the def asks the two fields what they are it knows how to find them.

All that said, use a class for things like this. If you're not clear on classes take a few days off from doing maya stuff to learn them - it's really important for the quality of your future code.

You should probably check out [Mechtley's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123785782) on Maya python (especially the chapter on GUI code). There are also useful discussions [here](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?3205-why-scriptJob-doesnt-work-in-case-of-attrControlGrp&highlight=scope), [here](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?3292-maya-python-UI-acessing-controls-from-external-functions&highlight=callback), and [here](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?2861-Seeing-root-space-python-instances-from-another-class-instance&highlight=callback)

PS: Somebody will probably post a fix that puts 'global' in front of time1 and time2 and 'global time1, time2' inside of the animate def. *Don't do it that way.* Globals = evil.